# Finding the roots of $\sec^2(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I need to find the roots of $\sec^2(x)=0$  in my works.

I know there are no real roots of this equation; are there complex roots?

Comment: $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{cos(x)}$ and $-1 \leq cos(x) \leq 1$ so the equation has no roots.

Comment: Yes, I know this but I need the complex roots

Comment: There are none of those either. Basically no roots.

Comment: Since $\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$ has no poles, $\frac{1}{\cos(z)}$ has no zeroes.

Comment: Since we want $1/cos^2(x)=0$ therefore $cos^2(x)$ must $\rightarrow$ infinity, but because $cos(x)\le 1$ hence we have no roots.

Comment: But we know that the number of roots is depending on the largest power of equation.If we convert the $sec^2(x)$ to the polynomial series by using Taylor series, we will get a function as follow       .$sec^2(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+......a_{n}x^n$                   .if we take the right side and solve it, we will get infinity roots.

Comment: @Ehegh: that is only true for polynomials. Note that $e^x=0$ has no solutions at all, yet it has a power series that converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sec(x)=\frac2{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}$ and since $e^{ix}$ is finite for all $x$, there is no $x\in\mathbb{C}$ that will make $\sec(x)=0$.

Comment: But we know that the number of roots is depending on the largest power of equation.If we convert the $sec^2(x)$ to the polynomial series by using Taylor series, we will get a function as follow       .$sec^2(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+......a_{n}x^n$                   .if we take the right side and solve it, we will get infinity roots.

Comment: @Ehegh: that is only true for polynomials. Note that $e^x=0$ has no solutions at all, yet it has a power series that converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

$tan(x)$ is monotonously increasing with no point yielding extrema, its derivative $sec^2(x)$ is never zero either for real or complex roots.